# Is doing !(!a && b) any less efficient than a || !b?

Tags: java, performance, logical-operators

I have a pathfinding algorithm which is run many times and must be extremely efficient, so I'm wondering what I can do to boost performance. I have an if statement which says this:

```
if (!(n != 1 && map.isCornerObstructed(p)) {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

It seems to me that the double inversion would take slightly longer than this logically equivalent version:

```
if (n == 1 || !map.isCornerObstructed(p)) {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

The problem is that the former is more readable in the context of the code, so I'm somewhat reluctant to change it if I don't know what the result will be.

Is one more efficient than the other? Or is the Java compiler smart enough to optimize things like this automatically?

Comment: Java's compiler by itself does very little optimisation. That's left for the JIT compiler. There probably is a way of obtaining the actual machine code that is run in Java too. But you should *profile* where your bottleneck is. I doubt your algorithm consists of a single `if`.

Comment: Why not just test it?  Write up a simplified example and run it 10k times, measure the resulting time.  Do this for each and compare the results. Then you will know beyond any reasonable doubt which is faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
int n = set.size();
Object o = new Object();
if (!(n != 1 && set.contains(o))) {
  System.out.println("Foo");
  // Do stuff...
}
```

generates bytecode

```
 0  new java.util.HashSet [16]
 3  dup
 4  invokespecial java.util.HashSet() [18]
 7  astore_1 [set]
 8  aload_1 [set]
 9  invokeinterface java.util.Set.size() : int [19] [nargs: 1]
14  istore_2 [n]
15  new java.lang.Object [3]
18  dup
19  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [8]
22  astore_3 [o]
23  iload_2 [n]
24  iconst_1
25  if_icmpeq 38
28  aload_1 [set]
29  aload_3 [o]
30  invokeinterface java.util.Set.contains(java.lang.Object) : boolean [25] [nargs: 2]
35  ifne 46
38  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [29]
41  ldc <String "Foo"> [35]
43  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) : void [37]
46  return
```

The code

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
int n = set.size();
Object o = new Object();
if (n == 1 || !set.contains(o)) {
  System.out.println("Foo");
  // Do stuff...
}
```

generates bytecode

```
 0  new java.util.HashSet [16]
 3  dup
 4  invokespecial java.util.HashSet() [18]
 7  astore_1 [set]
 8  aload_1 [set]
 9  invokeinterface java.util.Set.size() : int [19] [nargs: 1]
14  istore_2 [n]
15  new java.lang.Object [3]
18  dup
19  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [8]
22  astore_3 [o]
23  iload_2 [n]
24  iconst_1
25  if_icmpeq 38
28  aload_1 [set]
29  aload_3 [o]
30  invokeinterface java.util.Set.contains(java.lang.Object) : boolean [25] [nargs: 2]
35  ifne 46
38  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [29]
41  ldc <String "Foo"> [35]
43  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) : void [37]
46  return
```

which is *exactly* the same.  Therefore, there will be no performance difference *at all*, no matter how finely you measure it.  The compiled code is *identical.*

(Note that the reason for this is that `javac` actually goes and decomposes the `if` statement into individual condition tests and branches, so it actually works out the pathway for each possibility.)

Comment: Thanks. I *know* that an optimization such as this would be trivial anyway, but I still wanted to know if it would change anything. Thanks for resolving that for me!

Comment: Can you show how you generated the above output so others could do it themselves?

Comment: `javap Foo.class` does the job, or just opening up the `.class` file in Eclipse directly, which was what I did.

Answer (score 4):

Please focus on optimizing the complexity of your algorithm, rather than these micro-optimizations.

For this case, I see one comparison (`!=` and `==`), one logical operator, one negation. In the n != 1 case, the number of logical operations are the same. In the n == 1 case, the number of logical operations of the first case is more than the second case. If there are more n != 1 case, then **probably** doesn't matter. If there are more n == 1 case, then the second case **might** be minutely faster. But with the whole JIT compiler working behind, I don't know what really happens. Micro-optimization might work with C/C++ code, but I really doubt the effect on Java.

Comment: I agree, but this is more out of curiosity's sake than optimization. I'd just like to know if, *in theory*, one is more efficient.

Comment: For this case **only**, I see one comparison (`!=` and `==`), one logical operator, one negation. In the n != 1 case, the number of logical operations are the same. In the n == 1 case, the number of logical operations of the first case is more than the second case. If there are more n != 1 case, then **probably** doesn't matter. If there are more n == 1 case, then the second case **might** be minutely faster. But with the whole JIT compiler working behind, I don't know what really happens. Micro-optimization might work with C/C++ code, but I really doubt the effect on Java.

Answer (score 1):

My concern here would be the map.isCornerObstructed(p) call more than anything else, boolean logic is fast, but method calls not so much.

I'd go for the second option - that seems to be the easiest to read and most efficient.

As pointed out by the comments, both && and || short-circuit so you want the simplest way to test, using a wrapped inversion is just another layer that needs to execute.

Comment: @BheshGurung Thank you for pointing that out - just tested it , you are correct.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that time spent calling (and executing) `map.isCornerObstructed(p)` way outweighs any micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing that statement once here and there, who cares. Either one amounts to at most several cpu cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Second one could be more optimized.
but it depends on how many times , this part of your code is executed,

to be more specific , in your second option :

```
if (n == 1 || !map.isCornerObstructed(p)) {
// Do stuff...
}
```

if n==1 is true , java won't execute !map.isCornerObstructed(p) , and n==1 is more optimized than !map.isCornerObstructed(p) , so you must write your "if" statement in a way that in most times , the first and simpler statement shows the answer,

If you are in doubt that whether java optimize (!(n != 1 && map.isCornerObstructed(p)) , you can simply write a test case , 
run each of your statements a 1000000 times in a loop and use System.currentmils to calculate time cost of each method, and there you go

Comment: `||` is short-circuited if the left half evaluates to `true` just as `&&` is if the left half evaluates to `false`. The real question is if the compiler or JIT will turn `!(n != 1 && b)` into `(a == 1 || !b)`.

Comment: java converts !(something && something) to (!something || !something)

Suppose this test case : 
int a = 1; 
Object o = null ;

if (!(a == 0 && o.hashCode() ==0 )){
   System.err.println("IF");
}
else{
   System.err.println("ELSE");
}

if java does not convert if statement, it must throw exception, while it doesn't

Comment: No, because `&&` [short circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and `a == 0` evaluates to `false`, there's no need to evaluate `o.hashCode() == 0`. It has no bearing on the final result. `false && x` is `false` whether `x` is `true` or `false`, so `x` isn't evaluated.